# Why can't I load the OpenStreetMap R-Package?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, rjava

I installed the OpenStreetMap package in R but every time I load the package, I get the following error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘OpenStreetMap’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Can someone explain what could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: have you installed java ?

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is, but the `mapview` package is pretty painless.

Comment: The error message clearly implies you either haven't installed rJava or the registry entry for JAVA_HOME is not set properly..

Comment: Doesn'r rJava get installed when I install OpenStreetMap?

Comment: I just tried the mapview package and WOW! It is excellent! Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I setup JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add JAVA_HOME as a new PATH environment variable. I found all the usefull  informations about java here: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_HowTo.html